# Google Sites internal link

Tags: html, google-sites

I am trying to add internal links within my website. I know how to do it using google's GUI, but I am not sure how to do it using HTML. I have tried:

```
<a href="../page2.html">Go to page2</a>
<a href="/page2.html">Go to page2</a>
<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/page2.html/" taget="_self">Go to page2</a>
<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/page2.html/" taget="_parent">Go to page2</a>
```

All I want is to show the next page in the same tab.
None of them seems to work!
Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Don't put the slash after: `<a href="/page2.html">Go to page2</a>`

Comment: Try using the full URL

Comment: All the options I showed above, opens up a new tab. If I use the full URL, it opens up in another tab.